# Zebra label template with variables being sent

Tags: variables, printing, zpl

I need to be able to send a file to a Zebra ZD621 printer and use a template to fill in the variable data.  There is no way of changing the outgoing file to the printer.  What is being sent to the printer is:

```
C set printer's text buffer and overflow buffer size
VARIABLE TXTBFR 65536 64512
END
!* 0 0 0 0
C set printer to continuous mode
END
! 0 100 1200 1
C set printer to ASCII mode
C num labels is last value in "! 0..." string
U Al8X40(4,1,0) 15 10 Order: 55525003M/000
U Al8X40(4,1,0) 520 10 Line: 5
U Al8X40(4,1,0) 15 60 Consol. Lane: 01B
U Al8X40(4,1,0) 520 60 EMP: E0071194
U Al8X40(4,1,0) 15 110 TIN: M0073926
U Al8X40(4,1,0) 520 110 QTY: 4
U Al8X40(4,1,0) 15 160 Cust: GHX INCORPORATED
U Al8X40(4,1,0) 15 210 Desc: FTNG (PERM), 4-SPRL
U B18X40(4,1,0) 15 260 Supplier Item: 4S12FHB16
U Al8X40(4,1,0) 15 490 Cust Ord:
U Al8X40(4,1,0) 15 720 Cust Item:
U Al8X40(4,1,0) 15 950 Quantity Picked: 4
U Al2X25(4,1,0) 520 960 Date: 08/10/23
U Al2X25(4,1,0) 520 1010 Time: 07:34:52
BARCODE_FONT 18X23
BARCODE CODE39WX 120 460 150 4S12FHB16
BARCODE CODE39WX 120 690 150
BARCODE CODE39WX 120 920 150
BARCODE CODE39WX 120 1150 150 4
END
```

I have been able to somewhat make the template with the static fields but have no clue on where to even start on pulling the variables out.  Anything that is past a : is the variable being sent.  This is what I have done so far.  I really have no clue what I am doing and I only need this option for another 6 months.

```
^XA
:FILTER
INPUT DATA$

^FO15,10^ADN,15,16^FDOrder:^FS
^FO520,10^ADN,15,16^FDLine:^FS 
^FO15,60^ADN,15,16^FDConsol. Lane:^FS 
^FO520,60^ADN,15,16^FDEMP:^FS 
^FO15,110^ADN,15,16^FDTIN:^FS 
^FO520,110^ADN,15,16^FDQTY:^FS 
^FO15,160^ADN,15,16^FDCust:^FS 
^FO15,210^ADN,15,16^FDDesc:^FS 
^FO15,260^ADN,15,16^FDSupplier Item:^FS 
^FO15,490^ADN,15,16^FDCust Ord:^FS 
^FO15,720^ADN,15,16^FDCust Item:^FS 
^FO15,9500^ADN,15,16^FDQuantity Picked:^FS 
^FO520,960^ADN,15,16^FDDate:^FS 
^FO520,1010^ADN,15,16^FDTime:^FS 

ORDER$ = MID$(DATA$,23,LEN(DATA$)-22)
^FO250,15,16^N,100,Y,N^FDORDER$^FS

^ISR:SAMPLE.GRF^FS 
^XZ
```

I can no longer find the printers that are currently being used.